# Node.js:Unable to invoke pipe function

Tags: node.js, apigee, usergrid, apigee127

I am trying out a simple program to invoke a call to a backend & get the response back, here is my node.js code:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var stream = require('stream');


module.exports = {
 summary:summary
}

function summary(request, response) {
 var id = request.swagger.params.id.value;
 var url = "http://localhost:8080/test-org/myApp/summaries?q='id'";
 console.log('Executing request: '+url);
 request.get(url).pipe(response);
 };
```

However I get the following error:

```
curl http://localhost:10010/v1/customers/1123/summary
Executing request: http://localhost:8080/test-org/myApp/summaries?q='
id'
TypeError: Cannot call method 'pipe' of undefined
    at summary (C:\Apigee127\API-116\api\controllers\summary.js:17:19)
    at swaggerRouter (C:\Apigee127\API-116\node_modules\a127-magic\node_modules\
swagger-tools\middleware\2.0\swagger-router.js:114:18)
    at C:\Apigee127\API-116\node_modules\a127-magic\lib\middleware.js:82:9
    ....
```

Is there some npm package I am missing that I need to download?

-S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are breaking scoping. You function takes `request` but you also have loaded `var request = require('request')`.

Change it such that you have:

```
   var request = require('request');

   function summary(req, res) {
      request.get(url).pipe(res);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'pipe' of undefined` means that `request.get(url)` returns `undefined`. And yes, you cannnot call any function on `undefined` object.

So, why `request.get` results in undefined?

Can you modify the code to include some debugging?

```
  request.get(url)
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(response);
```

---

> Is there some npm package I am missing that I need to download?

https://www.npmjs.org/package/request lists 16 dependencies, but they were supposed to auto-download.

Comment: @Iwang135 if we are talking about https://github.com/request/request then no, it takes only one arguement - *url*

Comment: Sorry, I added an update. I got something confused. For the record, it _does_ take multiple arguments, but not necessary when using `.pipe`